# Reverse specific words

Tags: text, replace, reverse, notepad2

I am a beta tester for a hockey game and the csv file has the home and away teams reversed. The day, month, and year are correct though.

This:

```
20;1;1995;Toronto Maple Leafs;Los Angeles Kings 
20;1;1995;Buffalo Sabres;New York Rangers
20;1;1995;St. Louis Blues;San Jose Sharks
20;1;1995;Pittsburgh Penguins;Tampa Bay Lightning
20;1;1995;Dallas Stars;Vancouver Canucks
20;1;1995;Calgary Flames;Winnipeg Jets
```

To this:

```
20;1;1995;Los Angeles Kings;Toronto Maple Leafs
20;1;1995;New York Rangers;Buffalo Sabres
20;1;1995;St. Louis Blues;San Jose Sharks
20;1;1995;Tampa Bay Lightning;Pittsburgh Penguins
20;1;1995;Vancouver Canucks;Dallas Stars
20;1;1995;Winnipeg Jets;Calgary Flames
```

Of course this just a small sample...
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try replace all (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>) with regular expressions enabled

Use `(\d+;\d+;\d+;)([\s\S]+);([\s\S]+)` for your to replace value and `$1$3;$2` for your replace with value

Can't test it right now as I dont have Notepad++ installed on this computer... Tested it in Sublime and it worked.

Comment: Ctr+H>>>Replace Text box appears. Available options are: Search String and Replace with. Do those codes go in there?

Comment: http://markantoniou.blogspot.ca/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it manually after copying it to notepad regular then paste it all back again

find____________

replace________________

find toronto

replace  otnorot
)replace all parameter's(
etc

edless it is for a code to do it automatically

then your goin to need allot more integration for the compilation

I had a similiar qeustion before!